# How to get datas from firebase and save it inside an arraylist object?

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database structure:[image]

I want to get datas from a firebase database and save it inside an arraylist object to show the atributes of the object in a Textview on Android.

Ive tried this:

```
public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View mView;
    private Context context;
    TextView titularDetalle;
    public NewsViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titularDetalle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCabeceraDetalle);

        mView = itemView;
        context = itemView.getContext();
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatabaseReference myRef;
                myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("noticias");

                myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot noticia : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            clsNoticias noticias = noticia.getValue(clsNoticias.class);
                            ArrayList<clsNoticias> arrayNoticias = new ArrayList<clsNoticias>();
                            arrayNoticias.add(noticias);
                            titularDetalle.setText(noticias.getTitular());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityDetalle.class);
                //intent.putExtra("titular",titularDetalle);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }
```

First of all, I get a reference of all datas inside the database and im trying to get it, but I dont know well how to make this.

Moreover, when Ive done this it throws this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                    at
>   es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.Models.NewsViewHolder$1$1.onDataChange(NewsViewHolder.java:48)
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZT(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

This action is inside onClick on a item.

Someone knows how to fixed it?

Comment: share your database structure and simply make sure `titularDetalle` is not `null`

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your TextView first:

```
titularDetalle = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW_ID);
titularDetalle.setText(...);
```

That is the ID you defined in your layout XML for that TextView.

Comment: Ive done this...titularDetalle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCabeceraDetalle);

Answer (score 0):

Your `titularDetalle` variable is null!
You need to define an allocation space for it.

One of the ways to do that is calling

`titularDetalle = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TEXT_VIEW_ID);`

before trying to call `titularDetalle.setText(noticias.getTitular());`

Comment: `OnDataChange` is called asynchronously, remember that!

Comment: So, where should I get the data? Ive read the documentation and search information and `OnDataChange` Is in charge of update my datas if it suffers a new update

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to Firebase in this case. The error is stating `titularDetalle` is null, so it can't call `.setText()` on it.

Look to your layout XML for the RecyclerView item and make sure the `android:id` is the same name as the id you specify when initializing `titularDetalle` with the `findViewById()` method.